# Are all totient values of Fibonacci Numbers distinct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, conjectures

This question was inspired while I was seeing how certain recurrence relations would behave when I applied Multiplative Functions.

Let $F_{n}$ be a sequence for which $F_{1}=1,F_{2}=1$, and $F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$.
For any $n,m>8$, is it always true that  $\phi(F_n)$ is not equal to  $\phi(F_m)$, when  $\phi$ is the Euler Totient Function?

A case when $n$ divides $m$ appeared be rather simple.

$n|m$ would imply $F_{n}|F_{m}$.
Then let $F_{m}$ be $F_{n}$ multiplied by $k$.

$\phi(F_{m}) \ge \phi(F_{n})\phi(k)$.

$F_{n+1}=F_{n}+F_{n-1}<2F_{n}$, and  $F_{n+2}=2F_{n}+F_{n-1}>2F_{n}$.

Thus $k$ may never be equal to 2. Therefore, $\phi(k)$ will always be greater than 1 implying $\phi(F_{m})=\phi(k)\phi(F_{n})>\phi(F_{n})$.

Therefore, for the case when $n$ divides $m$, $\phi(F_m)$ is always not equal to $\phi(F_n)$ . 
However, other cases proved to be rather difficult, such as proving $\phi(F_n) \neq \phi (F_{n+1})$.

Can anybody prove or disprove this question? Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i wrote a code to check fibonacci numbers till 90, but couldn't find any such pairs. but i can't reason it

Comment: How Difficult do you think this question is?

Comment: I'd think the question is quite difficult. Fibonacci numbers aren't related by any strictly multiplicative relations, and after all they are growing quite fast. It's reasonable to expect that all totients are eventually distinct (the sequence of totients seems to grow quite fast as well), but I have no idea how the proof could go.

Comment: I am still relatively new to this site and want to ask some questions. First, it appear that while some questions have direct answers, others have just hints. How does one distinguish the two? Also, is it all right for me to asks questions that are unrelated to the question? If it is not all right, then where should I ask it? Finally, some people seemed to post their inspiration for the problem along with the question. Should I do this as well?

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Comment: @ChadShin Feel free to do so! This question of yours is, in my opinion, and interesting one, though it appears to be difficult. Don't feel discouraged by lack of feedback related to your questions. There are things which no one in this world can tell you whether they are true or not.

Comment: See [OEIS A$65449$](http://oeis.org/A065449).

Comment: Generally hints are given when the answerer thinks the question is homework.  Often others then post a full answer, but not always.  Showing where a question came from is appreciated, as it can help in deciding which ones to work on.  You might visit meta.math.stackexchange, where we discuss how the site should run

Comment: I should think that this is true for $8 < n < 1000$

Comment: Maybe you should try first $\phi(F_n)\ne \phi(F_{n+1})$.

Comment: @san How does one do so?

Comment: You have a very difficult problem, which remainds me of the Lehmer totient problem. 
Breaking down the problem to $\phi(F_k)=\phi(F_{k+1})$ eliminates the distraction
of some common factor (Note that $gcd(F_n,F_m)=F_{gcd(n,m)}$).
Even in that case I wouldn't expect the full answer, 
so try asking easier questions like: 1. Necessarily $k$ is odd? 
2. Is $k$ ($F_k$) squarefree?
3. Is $k$ ($F_k$) prime?

Similar questions have solution in the Lehmer totient problem, so maybe here you can make some progress, too.

Comment: From http://emis.ams.org/journals/JIS/VOL12/Mejia/luca31.pdf it is known that $\phi(F_{n+1})/\phi(F_n)$ can be arbitrarily large or small or arbitrary close to $1$.  So that probably rules out any approaches that purely use size considerations.

Comment: @ChadShin - Your question is good. You might get a much better answer if you posted it on [Mathematics Meta]{http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/}

Answer (score 1):

You have $\phi(5)=\phi(8)$, and $\phi(13)=\phi(21)$.

There is no really easy way, because the fibonacci numbers are the repunits of $j(-3),$ which means they are of the form $b^n+b^{-n}$, where $n=\frac 12(\sqrt{j+2}+\sqrt{j-2})$. This means that there is no particular rule that the period of a prime must divide the totient of the prime.

Comment: The question restricts the indices to be $> 8$, so these examples are excluded.